# Optimizing assembly for ARM

Tags: assembly, arm

I am trying to write an asm function that generates 16 samples into a buffer which is output at 48k from the codec.
Each sample adds 16 sine waves together and each sine or partial has an ADSR envelope with additional delay stage (wait) to control the amplitude. Its additive synthesis in other words.
Anyway I'm pissed because the compiler in CooCox can actually do this faster than all my sweat in ASM. What could I do to optimize this and make it faster? There are a lot of control parameters involved which makes for a lot of loads from global array variables that slows it down. This is for STM32F4 BTW.

```
    @ ARM function definition
    @ void get_sine(void)
        .align 2                    @ Align to word boundary
        .global get_sine       @ This makes it a real symbol
        .syntax unified @ Remember this!
        .type get_sine STT_FUNC    @ Declare to be a function.
        .equ bufsize, 1024
        .equ partials, 16
        .equ MAX_EG, 524288
        .data
    count16: .word 0x0


get_sine:                  @ Start of function definition
        push    {r4-r12}
        ldr     r2,=sineLUT     @   sine_tab base addy
        ldr     r9,=atk
        ldr     r10,=dcy
        ldr     r11,=sus
        ldr     r12,=rel
        ldr     r6,=env_1
        ldr     r1,=count16
        mov     r0,#0
        str     r0,[r1,#0]
outloop:
        ldr     r7,=ph_inc      @   pitch val into r7
        ldr     r7,[r7,#0]      @   get current phase
        ldr     r3,=phase       @   phase address to r3
        ldr     r1,[r3,#0]      @   get current phase
        add     r1,r1,r7        @   add current phase and ph_inc
        str     r1,[r3,#0]      @   store phase
        mov     r7,#0           @   set to 1 for r7 to be inner loop counter
        mov     r5,#0           @   clear sum reg
        ldr     r8,=flag
        ldr     r3,=EG_stage

innerloop:
        ldr     r0,[r3,r7,lsl #2]   @get EG_stage r0
        cmp     r0,#0               @ if zero goto wait
        beq     waitj
        cmp     r0,#1               @ if 1 jump attack
        beq     attackj
        cmp     r0,#2               @ if 2 jump decay
        beq     decayj
        b       releasej                @ if 3 jump release

waitj:
        ldr     r1,=wait_temp       @get wait_temp array addr
        ldr     r0,[r1,r7,lsl #2]   @load value to r0
        sub     r0,r0,#1            @subtract
        mov     r4,#1               @ load one for next
        cmp     r0,#0               @compare if gt or equal to zero
        ite     ge
        strge   r0,[r1,r7,lsl #2]   @ store wait state if >= 0
        strlt   r4,[r3,r7,lsl #2]   @ store EG_stage value if less than
        b break

attackj:
        ldr     r0,[r6,r7,lsl #2]   @ get env1 value into r0
        ldr     r1,[r9,r7,lsl #2]   @ get attack value
        add     r0,r0,r1            @   env_1[par] += atk[par];
        mov     r4,#2
        mov     r1,MAX_EG
        cmp     r0,r1
        itte    GE                  @   if (env_1[par] >= MAX)
        strge   r4,[r3,r7,lsl #2]   @   EG_stage[par] = 2, env_1[par] = MAX;
        strge   r1,[r6,r7,lsl #2]
        strlt   r0,[r6,r7,lsl #2]
        b break

decayj:
        ldr     r0,[r6,r7,lsl #2]   @ get env1 value into r0
        ldr     r1,[r10,r7,lsl #2]  @ decay value
        sub     r0,r0,r1            @   env_1[par] -= dcy[par];
        str     r0,[r6,r7,lsl #2]   @ update env_1 now in case
        ldr     r4,[r11,r7,lsl #2]  @   get sus value
        add     r1,r4,r1            @ add decay and sus value for compare
        cmp     r0,r1               @ if < sus[par]+dcy[par] || env_1[par]<0)
        ittt    lt
        movlt   r0,r4               @env_1[par] = (sus[par]);
        strlt   r4,[r6,r7,lsl #2]   @ store to env_1
        blt     break
        cmp     r0,#0
        itt     lt                  @|| env_1[par]<0)
        movlt   r0,r4               @env_1[par] = (sus[par]);
        strlt   r4,[r6,r7,lsl #2]   @ store to env_1
        b break

releasej:
        ldr     r0,[r6,r7,lsl #2]   @ get env1 value into r0
        ldr     r1,[r12,r7,lsl #2]  @ release value
        sub     r0,r0,r1            @ env_1[par] -= rel[par];
        str     r0,[r6,r7,lsl #2]   @ update env_1 now in case
        mov     r1,#0
        cmp     r0,#0               @
        it      lt                  @ if (env_1[par]<0)
        strlt   r1,[r6,r7,lsl #2]   @ env_1[par] = 0;

break:
        mov     r4,#0
        add     r4,r7,#1
        ldr     r1,=phase           @ phase address to r3
        ldr     r1,[r1,#0]
        umull   r0,r4,r1,r4         @ multiply phase for each partial
        lsr     r0,r0,#18           @ shift it right by 18 into r0 for sine_tab lookup
        ldr     r0,[r2,r0,lsl #2]   @ lookup sine val with r0 into r1 and sign extend
        ldr     r4,[r6,r7,lsl #2]   @ get envelope value into r4
        lsr     r4,r4,#4            @ shift it to 16bit range   
        smulbb  r0,r0,r4            @ signed multiply of sine table * envelope for scaling
        asr     r0,r0,#15           @ asr shift back to 16bit
        ldr     r4,[r8,r7,lsl #2]   @ get flag if withing bandwidth
        cmp     r4,#0               
        it      ne                  @ if 1 add it to sum
        addne   r5,r5,r0            
        add     r7,r7,#1
        cmp     r7,#16              @ compare loop index with 16 (i=0;i<16;i++)
        bne     innerloop

        asr     r0,r5,#5
        pkhbt   r0,r0,r0,lsl #16    @   pack R+L channel in r0
        ldr     r5,=writePos    @   get writepos addr
        ldr     r1,[r5,#0]      @   get writePos
        lsl     r3,r1,#2        @   align address 4
        ldr     r4,=WaveBuffer  @   storage array addy
        str     r0,[r4,r3]      @   store sine to WaveBuffer
        add     r1,r1,#1        @   increment array pointer writepos
        mov     r3,bufsize      @   load BUFFERSIZE compare
        cmp     r1,r3           @   skip if less than BUFFERSIZE
        it      hs
        movhs   r1,#0           @   clr writepos if >=BUFFERSIZE
        str     r1,[r5,#0]      @   store writepos value

        ldr     r0,=dataSize    @   get datasize counter addr
        ldr     r1,[r0,#0]      @   get val
        add     r1,r1,#1        @   increment datasize counter
        str     r1,[r0,#0]      @   store counter
        ldr     r1,=count16
        ldr     r0,[r1,#0]
        add     r0,r0,#1        @   increment loop counter
        str     r0,[r1,#0]
        cmp     r0,#16      @   compare with 16 (i=0;i<16;i++)
        bne     outloop
        pop     {r4-r12}
        bx      lr



    .section .rodata
        sineLUT:
        @ Array goes in here. Type can be .byte, .hword or .word
        @ NOTE! No comma at the end of a line! This is important

    .word   0x0000,0x000c,0x0018,0x0024,0x0030,0x003c,0x0048,0x0054
    .word   0x0064,0x0070,0x007c,0x0088,0x0094,0x00a0,0x00ac,0x00bc
    .word   0x00c8,0x00d4,0x00e0,0x00ec,0x00f8,0x0104,0x0114,0x0120
    .word   0x012c,0x0138,0x0144,0x0150,0x015c,0x016c,0x0178,0x0184
    .word   0x0190,0x019c,0x01a8,0x01b4,0x01c4,0x01d0,0x01dc,0x01e8
    .word   0x01f4,0x0200,0x020c,0x021c,0x0228,0x0234,0x0240,0x024c
```

Comment: This topic has been covered several times on StackOverflow before. Writing assembly language doesn't guarantee you'll do a good job of it. The first thing to notice in your code is a total disregard for the arm instruction pipeline. Register loads are not immediately available for use and you have pipeline stalls at almost every instruction. You use 16-bit values, yet load them as 32-bit values. When you have more than 13 16-bit variables to juggle you need to get creative and use the top/bottom halves of registers. Lots of areas in your code to improve...

Comment: you have pipeline stalls at almost every instruction.
I am not sure I understand what you mean here can you explain how I would overcome this?

Comment: ARM CPU's have an instruction execution pipeline which breaks up each operation into several steps so that things can occur in parallel. The net effect allows for each instruction to take "1 clock cycle". One result is that when loading a register from memory, the register will not be "ready" on the next instruction. You need to avoid using the same register after loading it by interleaving other instructions in between the load and use of the register. See some of my answers with ARM code for examples.

Comment: Ok thanks I understand now. I tried your suggestions with the code I posted and did see some gains. Not huge mind you but the compiler still beats me. A lot of the loads are needed to process the subsequent instructions so not a lot of other stuff to do in between. Getting more of the global variables into registers would probably help but most of them are 32bit values so splitting into halfwords is difficult. I got it down so it is just slightly slower than the compiler but was hoping for better performance for all my efforts. I keep working on it though.

Comment: By chance, was the compiler using the FPU? The FPU registers on Cortex-M4F can be easily moved to/from integer registers, so you can use them as fast buffering, and also for another way to load/store memory. For example, to free up R13+R14 for math, save them to the FPU after your push. Look for VLDR,VLDM,VMOV,VSTM,VSTR being emitted. RVCT4.1 does this on functions that only use integer operations.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to learn how your compiler does this is compile your code in that compiler, then look at the assembly it outputs. It will probably be confusing, since it is so optimized, but you might be able to pick up some tricks.

One trick, that is highly unreadable, but might help, is to implement some sort of "jump table
" functionality. In inner loop, instead of doing 3 compare statements, add (r0*X) to the current instruction pointer. At the appropriate destination, have an unconditional jump instruction into wherever you need to go (attacks,decayj,releasej). The value of X will be based on how many bytes are needed to hold the jump instructions. That's just an idea I had, you need to test it yourself for efficacy.

Comment: yeah jump table would be good. It looks like ADR instruction might help for this. I have tried looking at the compiler output but it is such a jumble due to way it access variable registers using immediate s

Comment: I can't get the jump table working. None of the examples I can find seem to work with my tools. Manipulating the pc just gets me an exception. I went with a cmp but start with 1 so now its:

      `cmp r0,#1
      blt wait
      beq attack
      cmp r0,#2
      beq decay
      bgt release`

so only two compares. I noticed this is how CooCox handles case switches and not even this well optimized.

Comment: If you modify the pc you have to take into account that the value you're reading is already advanced by 2 words. So if you do add pc, pc, #8 you will not jump over the next instruction but in fact the next 3.

Comment: Ok that probably explains it. I was trying to use the tbb and tbh and the examples all use syntax that seems to be Keil specific and i can't get working in gcc. The dcb and dci instructions specifically.